# How to manage background requests reliably?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, asihttprequest

I need to asynchronously run a query against a http server and handle the response. The query is really *a pretty large chain of method calls with callbacks*. This adds complexity because there are a lot of return paths during the chain of calls.

It should not be possible to start a new request until the current one is completely completed.

Here is the general outline:

1. Some thread calls `[Foo poll]`.
2. The `poll` method starts a couple of HTTP requests which runs in the background. In this case ASIHTTPRequest.
3. The requests eventually calls `[Foo onRequestComplete]` which parses the response. On error `[Foo onRequestError`] is called. This is a second return path.
4. Then more calls are done to the server, with callbacks and more return paths.
5. Eventually saving some stuff to disk.
6. The poll is complete

Here is the catch: During these steps, calls to `poll` should be ignored (returned) or blocked  until the poll is complete.

**How can you make sure the `poll` function blocks or no-ops while another poll is running?**

Comment: One very näive approach is to add a `Server.isBusy` property, but that is not thread safe and very messy to maintain, considering error handling paths etc. What about GCD, blocks or synchronized?

Comment: Locks or GCD - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `NSLock`.

In `[Foo poll]`:

```
if ([lock tryLock]) {
    // Do your stuff
}
```

In `[Foo onRequestComplete]`:

```
[lock unlock];
```

Comment: It's a bit messy to maintain. You need to add `lock` and `unlock` calls all over the place (essentially in every possible return path, callbacks etc). I have an annoying feeling there ought to be a more streamlined approach to this, probably using GCD, but I can't see it. Frustrating.

Comment: @Martin Wickman: The way you formulated the question, it sounded like you had one entry point and one callback. You probably have a callback for when the request fails, but that's still just three places where you need to mind the lock. If you have enough return paths to make this lock solution messy to maintain, maybe it's the number of return paths that's the problem and not the lock?

Comment: This is more of a transaction consisting of a sequence of (http, parse, http, http, ..., save to disk, done). There is one entry point for locking, but each step has its own callback, which makes it very easy to miss an `unlock` somewhere. But unless there is no other way, I'll guess this is the answer.

Comment: @Martin I was under the impression that you have a `FooDelegate` or similar, to notify the caller that their poll request has finished. Would it be to hard to put `[lock unlock]` right before you notify the delegate? I guess most people just go with the lock solution and don't bother looking any further.

Comment: Lol, yes you're absolutely right. That's where this eventually ended up. Thanks!